# Remarkable markdown. Get actual text length

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, markdown

I am creating a markdown editor with a `textarea` and Remarkable. I only want to submit if the length of the text is greater than a minimum value. How can I get the actual length of the text that is is seen in my output

```
 var CharCounter = React.createClass({

    getText : function(){
        if(this.props.count < this.props.min)
            return (this.props.min - this.props.count) + ' more to go';
        else if(this.props.count < this.props.max)
            return (this.props.max - this.props.count) + ' left';
        else
            return 'Done';

    },
    render : function(){
        return(
            <p><small>{this.getText()}</small></p>
        );
    }
});
```

The problem is that if I try and use the text area value directly. The length includes markdown .ie ['*', '**']

Answer (score 2):

You should add some code, some reference.

The right answer could be

```
if(textarea.value.length > minLength) /* do something */
```

or

```
var submittable = $(textarea).text().length > minLength;
return submittable;
```

Comment: great, can you also add where you bind the Remarkable lib ?

Comment: I would say: the `render` method outputs html, I would then put it in a div and get the `.text().length` via jQuery.